# How to create 2 action bars in one app?

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

Is it possible to create 2 action bars (using action bar sherlock) in one app?

I want to have on top navigation standard action bar and on bottom to have Tab Activities.

If there is no way to do this with actionbarsherlock.

Maybe some one done this using FragmentActivity. I mean TabHost as i have tried to do Tab host with TabActivity but it's from 3.0 deprecated and need to be done with FragmentActivity. 
My app should support from API 7 to API 15.
It would be nice for some examples.

Comment: "and on bottom to have Tab Activities" -- tabs on the bottom is a UI anti-pattern. See "Don't use bottom tab bars" in the Android Design documentation: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. ActionBarSherlock (4.0) is basically a port of the Android 4.0 (ICS) action bar related code, so it can only do what native Android does. This means:

- you can have tabs (or custom navigation) in the top bar
- you can have a separate (split) action bar with action buttons at the bottom on phones (narrow screen)

To implement tabs, you need to use fragments, not TabHost/Activity, etc. There are examples in the samples/ directory of ABS.